# How to set axios globally in Angular17 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I had in Vue.js axios config file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1';
```

so i didnt have to use URL in all the API request across the app.
Now i created  axios.ts file in Angular17 project in src folder:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1';
export default axios;
```

But i dont know to globally use it across the whole app, and dont import it in every service file.

i want to change:

```
const res = await axios.get(http://localhost:8000/api/v1/card);
```

to

```
const res = await axios.get('/card');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, importing what is needed is the usual way, instead of having global configs and settings, which is why it's better to [create a service](https://angular.io/guide/creating-injectable-service) which uses axios, and then import it where needed.

But you could add axios [globally to the runtime global scope](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#adding-a-library-to-the-runtime-global-scope) via angular.json, and then setup your config in root component (or instead load it via CDN script tag in index.html):

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"
],
```

modify settings it in the root component:

```
// usage with typescript
// declare var axios:any;

export class App {

  constructor() {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1';       
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

and then in some component:

```
// usage with typescript
// declare var axios:any;

export class SomeComponent {

  async ngOnInit() {

    const res = await axios.get('/card');
```

Guide: [Usage of Angular libraries published to npm](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries)